# Disabling AdMob Ads in certain parts of app

Tags: java, android, admob, opengl-es-2.0, ads

My App, (OpenGL ES 2.0) currently has 55 classes, and one activity single.

I have my own custom Scene Manager which I use to change between different Scenes (ie, different scenes would be: Main Menu, Level Select, Level 1, Level 2....Level 20, Game Over etc...)

So I set all of my AdMob stuff up in my Activity's onCreate(); method.  So at the moment, the same ad runs throughout the whole app.

How it is possible to 'switch off' the ads on different Scenes?

Bear in mind that none of my classes have direct access to the Activity class itself.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I'm finding using AdMob extremely challenging, it doesn't seem very intuitive so any AdMob experts out there, your opinions would be appreciated!

I should point out that I don't use XML, everything is done programmatically.

Thanks

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(TestDeviceID)
          .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Request full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Create a displayMetrics object to get pixel width and height
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;

        //Work out values for resizing screen while keeping aspect ratio

        width = (int) Math.min(width, height * 1.702127659574468);
        height = (int) Math.min(height, width / 1.702127659574468);

        //Create and set GL view (OpenGL View)
        myView = new MyGLSurfaceView(MainActivity.this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        //Set the colour if we don't, the ad won't show (bug?)
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        layout.addView(myView);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        //Create a copy of the Bundle
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            newBundle = new Bundle(savedInstanceState);         
        }


        setContentView(layout);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're causing yourself a lot of pain by doing your layout programmatically (I gave a talk on this just last night). You should really consider understanding and using the XML layout.

But to answer your question, you will need to find a way for the classes that want to control whether an ad is shown or not to have some method of sending a message to the Activity. I would suggest injecting them with an interface that is implemented by an inner classes in your Activity.

The interface is going to need to look something like:
 - startShowingAds - this should start requesting ads and make the AdView visible.
 - stopShowingAds - this should pause ad showing and hide the AdView.

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily hide the ads you just need to hide the AdView, eventually calling pause() even though I think that hidden ad views are not refreshed (you can check in the logs).

About how to reach the AdView object from your code, it depends on what you have accessible from there. If you just have the View where you are drawing a solution could be to store the AdView object in the View's tag (see setTag() and getTag() here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29).